# Grammar problems

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I'm reading a book. The author wrote:

> "I boxed them up along with my father's papers, stored them away, promising one day to sort them out. All I managed to do was deaden myself to them, *detach* myself from life. That works for only so long."

Why doesn't ***detach*** have to change into ***detached***, since he was talking about the past?

Also, this one:

> "We planned to go to he hospital on Christmas day, *record* our conversation."

Why is it ***record*** and not ***recorded***?

Comment: "All I managed to do **was (to) detach** myself...". As for the other one "We planned to go to the hospital, **(and we planned to) record** our conversation.

Comment: Advice: Stop worrying about which English tense to use. Native speakers use both and don't notice or care. What they ***do*** care about is being able to ask a grammatical question in English. Until one learns to do that, study time spent on tense issues is wasted. To solve your grammar problems, learn syntax. Correct questions would be: _Why doesn't 'detach' have to change ..?_ and _Why is it 'record' and not 'recorded'?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the superfluous:

> ... I managed ( to ... detach ... )
>
> ... We planned  ( to ... record ... )

The verb already indicates the tense.

Answer (score 0):

Its because if it is a continuous thing like: 
'All I managed to do was deaden myself to them and all I managed to do was to detach myself from life.' 
You can directly specify as 'All I managed to do was deaden myself to them, detach myself from life.'

Similarly in the second case, 
'We planned to go to he hospital on Christmas day and we planned to record our conversation.'
Can be specified as 
'We planned to go to he hospital on Christmas day, record our conversation.'

No need of specifying the same elements again and again. :)